# Multi-threading and Sockets. multiple room chat service over one socket

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, pickle

Is there any way to go about having a multi room chat service, using multi-threading and sockets, while using one socket? This is all very new to me and am not sure how to go about using sockets and assigning each room their own socket that users can change to within our GUI. So on a single server you have the ability to create different rooms and then change to those rooms from the GUI. I've looked into pickling as a way to send the data from different chat rooms over the single socket but am not sure if there is an easier way. Any tips would help!